# Making a single finger rotation gesture

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, uigesturerecognizer, image-rotation

Im creating a game where the user needs to invoke a single finger rotation gesture which would recognize a user's full 360 degree rotation around a centre point to award a point. I also and looking for a way for the image to rotate following the angle at which the players finger is located. I personally am not to familiar with gestures as I am fairly new with Xcode so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. The rotation recognizer needs two fingers, so that is not a viable solution I think.

In the handling routine of the recognizer you would have to start tracking the starting point when the state of the recognizer is `.Began`. The pan recognizer has a property called `velocity` which is a kind of direction vector. You could use that and / or the collected points (`locationInView`) which you could keep track of to determine the approximate midpoint.

The algorithm would have to be somewhat heuristic, I guess. For example, if you know the point in question you could simply store the vectors to the point in an array and then determine if the distance to the point is within a certain range. This would be a good approach also if you have several possible points, but don't yet know which one it is.

If you need to determine an arbitrary point it gets more tricky as you have to work with multiple hypotheses. Perhaps this would be a case for a separate question on SOF.

The problem of having an object turn into the direction of the finger is easy. You know the location for each point of the drag in the drag handler, so you can change the `transform` property of the view you want to rotate. You can set it to a `CGAffineTransform` of kind rotation based on the finger position as measured from the center of the view to be rotated.

If you study the mentioned APIs, you will be able to accomplish your task easily.